# Single Xtext Language Server for two extensions

Tags: xtext

I have two Eclipse plugin Xtext(2.11) projects.(Called Project A and B) Project B grammar file is dependent on Project A grammar file. Project A's grammar file extension is a and Project B is b.
I am able to generate the language server for Project B. I want to generate the single language server for both projects.(Currently, in project B it includes project A.)
Depend on extension type it needs invoke respective Xtext grammar functionality.

In above scenario, I have below questions:

1. Does Xtext can handle this kind of scenario seamlessly? Do I need to generate the language server for Project A also and need to add in Project B? What is the best way to do this?
2. What kind of Xtext changes required?
3. What kind of changes required at client side also? like in Visual code/ Che?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Xtext LS can be used with multiple Xtext languages. It uses java service loading to look up language setups: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext/src/org/eclipse/xtext/resource/ResourceServiceProviderServiceLoader.xtend#L25. In ide project of your language you should be able to find `META-INF/services/org.ecalipse.xtext.ISetup` file that says java what implementations should be used for `ISetup` interface.
2. Having jars for ide projects on the classpath should be enough. No changes are required.
3. VS code and Che does not care about implementation details of Xtext LS, but both languages should be registered for them

Comment: I am still not able to see the language server gets activated for my 'a' extension. Does there any blog or documents for this integration?

How will the VS code know about 'a' extension?

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly, then I need to do nothing except adding the A projects ide modules jar in B's ide module. Can you please add more focus on this area?

Comment: true for vs code you need to register your language, you can look at this tutorial to learn how to do it: http://typefox.io/building-a-vs-code-extension-with-xtext-and-the-language-server-protocol

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have followed that blog and my LS server gets integrated with VsCode only for my project B. I can not get the Xtext feature for my Project A. I want to see both languages to be activated at same time.

Comment: Have you changed "activationEvents" and "contributes" sections in package.json to support both languages: https://github.com/TypeFox/languageserver-example/blob/master/vscode-extension/package.json#L14?

Comment: also `documentSelector` should be changed: https://github.com/TypeFox/languageserver-example/blob/master/vscode-extension/src/extension.ts#L26

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138200/discussion-between-chetan-laddha-and-anton-kosyakov).